# Discontinuity of the identity function in topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

According to a theorem I was taught, the identity function $id(x)=x$ from $(\mathbb{R},  \tau_1)$ to $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_2)$ is continuous if $\tau_1 = \tau_2$. Are there any examples of topologies $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ on the real line such that this doesn't hold?

Comment: I think that $\tau_2\subset \tau_1$ suffices.

Comment: Discrete topology vs usual topology could be an example.

Comment: But are there any standard topology examples that make it discontinuous? I am trying to digest the discontinuity haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there are.

If $\tau_1$ is the standard topology and $\tau_2$ is the discrete topology, i.e., $\tau_2=\mathscr P(\mathbb R)$ (that means that every subset of $\mathbb R$ is $\tau_2-$open), then the identity map
$$
I : (\mathbb R,\tau_1) \to (\mathbb R,\tau_2),
$$
is not continuous since, if $U\subset\mathbb R$ is not $\tau_1-$open, while however  it is $\tau_2-$open, then
$I^{-1}(U)=U\not\in \tau_1$, while $U\in\tau_2$.

Comment: Oh I understand now. Thank you so much! :)